# Combination of similar pronouns (indefinite)

Tags: pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

Are there any significant differences in meaning or usage between `"everyone"` and `"everybody"`, or `"anybody"` and `"anyone"`?

As far as I know, there are some grammatical points involving 
`"everyone"` and `"everybody"`, or `"anybody"` and `"anyone"`, but books/internet/professors cannot identify any differences of meaning or usage between these two pronouns.

Comment: I would say any difference that does exist is either unimportant or imagined. You're safe using them interchangeably outside of set idioms.

Comment: Thanks, `everyone is singular and it must paired with a singular verb` is this a correct usage???

Comment: Yes, everyone/everybody is singular, as is anyone/anybody.

Comment: It is. However, as the OED says, ‘The pronoun referring to "every one" is often plural: the absence of a singular pronoun of common gender rendering this violation of grammatical concord sometimes necessary.’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’, Pam Peters reports that, while both forms are in regular use in the UK and the US, the forms with *-one* are more frequent. The forms with *–body* are most commonly found in conversation and used more freely in American than British fiction.

Comment: Does this mean that people in the U.K. perceive *-one* as a significantly more formal word?

Comment: I think we'd need more evidence to draw that conclusion.