# "Anyone knows that" vs. "everyone knows that"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, any-every

The context is as follows.

I say that X is true.  The (dismissive) response I receive is "Anyone knows that".  Is that a complete sentence? Yes, it is grammatical. Yes,it has some semblance of meaning.

Firstly: most people wouldn't see a problem — they would interpret *anyone* as *everyone* without thinking about it. But, as other discussions in this forum note, *anyone* and *everyone* are not precise synonyms.

Secondly: by inferring an implied set of people, the sentence "Anyone knows that" makes sense, e.g., "Anyone (you could possibly ask) knows that." I agree that most listeners/readers would make this inference without thinking about it.

But note that this interpretation of "Anyone knows that", is only an example. There are other possibilities for implied sets of people. Therefore, it seems to me that if the meaning of *anyone* is intended to mean all, the sentence is incomplete.  What do you think?

Comment: A sentence is not "incomplete" just because it doesn't necessarily mean what it's supposed to mean, or because it might be ambiguous. You agree that this sentence is grammatical and clear. "Anyone knows that" may not be idiomatic, but it's certainly not "incomplete".

Comment: Well, maybe it's only an elided version of "Anyone other than you would know that" grammatified to 3rd person singular because the modal has been left out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "anyone" and "everyone" in this context](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77058/what-is-the-difference-between-anyone-and-everyone-in-this-context)

Answer (score 2):

The choice of *anyone* or *everyone* has no bearing on whether OP's sentence is "complete". The issue there is simply whether *"that"* refers *back* to some fact previously mentioned...

> Speaker A: *"Pigs can't fly!"* Speaker B: *"Everyone knows that."* ("that" refers back to A's statement).
>
> Speaker A: *"Everyone knows that pigs can't fly!"* ("that" refers forward, or to implied "**the fact** that").

---

Regarding the actual choice of [indefinite pronoun](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/pronouns-indefinite.htm) *(anybody, anyone, anything, each, everybody, everyone, everything, few, many, nobody, none, one, several, some, somebody, someone, etc.)* there's no special *grammatical* reason for the overwhelming preference...

> ["but everyone knows that..."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20everyone%20knows%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (74700 instances in Google Books).
>
> ["but anyone knows that..."](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20anyone%20knows%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (430 instances)

To a large extent,  it's just the established idiomatic usage. But the preference reverses with...

> ["everyone **can** do that"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20everyone%20can%20do%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22everyone%20can%20do%20that%22&oq=%22everyone%20can%20do%20that%22&gs_l=serp.3...189256.192172.3.192892.8.8.0.0.0.0.92.450.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.XpC_KQF-g7s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893) (9,690 instances)
>
> ["anyone **can** do that"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22but%20everyone%20can%20do%20that%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22anyone%20can%20do%20that%22&oq=%22anyone%20can%20do%20that%22&gs_l=serp.3...4976.7088.2.7846.8.8.0.0.0.0.61.399.8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.P8f_XN6qRl0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b49692da6db40a6a&bpcl=38625945&biw=1116&bih=893) (56,200 instances)

...which I attribute partly to the fact that *everyone* effectively means *all people, collectively,* whereas *anyone* means *any **one particular** person chosen at random*.

When the associated verb is **can**, the "deed" is a single action (not even *actual*, just *potential*), so it makes more sense to link it to one person (any one you care to pick). But if you **know** something, and others know the same thing, it's more emphatic to say that *all* people know it (all the time).